# Wrong notification and settings icon for Flutter Android app with product flavors

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a Flutter project and I want to have two apps from the same source code, the main difference between those apps are just the name, app icon, colors, and few other minor details.

I have added productFlavors in the build.gradle with ABC and TCD flavors.

I have created the TCD folder and added res folder and generated app icons with appicon.co and added them inside the TCD folder.

The issue that I have is that when I get a push notification it always displays the ABC app icon, instead of the TCD app icon. Also, if I go to the phone settings and find the TCD app it shows the ABC app icon.

Here is the image of my folder structure.

[image]

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using Firebase Cloud Messaging to send your notifications directly from the console, did you follow the instructions on setting custom notification icons:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#edit-the-app-manifest

When sending via Firebase Cloud Messaging you will need to change your Manifest accordingly, and have a separate resource file for the icon.

If you are using a third party service to send push notifications, they might have additional things for you to do in order to have a different notification icon.

Note: I think that icons that you are showing the in screenshot are only used as launcher icons. Those 2 are 2 different setups.

Comment: Thanks for the response Vladimir. Initially, I did not have the meta data tag with the icon for push notifications, but I have tried that also and the icon is still wrong.  The other thing is if I open phone settings and find the app there it has wrong icon or if press button to show active apps it has wrong icon. While in the app launcher menu it has correct icon. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Actually, it works notification icon, thanks. It seems that I was putting <meta-data> at the wrong place. I still have strange issue that the app icon is wrong in all other place expect launcher menu.

Comment: Well regarding the launcher icon, make sure that you have the launcher icon resource available in all sizes in all directories setup properly. Also make sure that you are using the same name in the AndroidManifest.xml file under the <application> tag. My best guess is that you are missing some of the resource files under the specific flavor directory. @Zookey

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am suspecting the same, but I can not find the root of the issues. If you look at the image, I have ach mipmap folder with the app_icon for both flavors (main and tcd). Do you have some ideas?

Comment: It seems that the app icon works in the app settings works fine with emulator, but it still shows wrong icon on my Samsung phone.

Comment: @Zookey it might be that Samsung is caching the icon for some reason. It might help to just uninstall the app, and restart the phone. Maybe that clears the system cache. Maybe worth trying on more devices.